# Numpy reports error with multiarray module

Tags: python

I'm working on making a simple visz with bokeh but having a trouble with bokeh server. Here is my example code

```
# myapp.py

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc

plot = figure()
plot.line(x = [1,2,3,4,5], y = [2,5,4,6,7])

curdoc().add_root(plot)
```

I'm using window so I command `bokeh server --show myapp.py` but got this error.

```
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Is there anything I missed to connect with bokeh server? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Your code ran without error on my machine after pip installing the bokeh package.

Comment: Hi natersoz. Do I need to install bokeh package even if there is no problem running the code with spyder?

Comment: I tried the same, `pip install bokeh`, but still doen't work with same error. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error has nothing to do with Bokeh directly. Your Numpy package installation is completely broken. You will need to uninstall Numpy, possibly deleting any Numpy related files out of your site packages by hand, and reinstall it as the error suggests.

Comment: Hi bigreddot. So can I just uninstall it by `pip uninstall numpy` ? and then reinstall?

Comment: And could you explain me why this is related to numpy? I suspected numpy but couldn't understand it cause there is no numpy command in the code.

Comment: Bokeh uses Numpy internally. That pip command is a good start but may not be sufficient. You will just have to try it and see.

Comment: Alternatively, look at the Anaconda distribution to install python, and compiled packages like numpy, especially on Windows. https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: Okay, so I reinstalled numpy and tried again but got the different error this time..
`error: invalid choice: 'server' (choose from 'html', 'info', 'json', 'png', 'sampledata', 'secret', 'serve', 'static', 'svg')`
Do I need to reinstall bokeh as well?

Comment: It's "bokeh serve", not "bokeh server"

Comment: Oh..Yeap. perfect! Thanks a lot bigreddot :-)